# how to force change the dependency of mudule in gradle

Tags: gradle

I am using coody-elock lib to using redis in my project :

```
api("org.coody.framework:coody-elock:alpha-1.2.4")
```

when I run project it give me error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/params/SetParams
```

I trace to source code and find the coody-elock using jredis 2.9.1,but my project is using 3.0.1 and I check the 3.0.1 has SetParam class.This is my jredis import using gradle 6.0:

```
api("redis.clients:jedis:3.0.1")
```

and now how to change the jredis to using 3.0.1 not 2.9.1?This is what I already tried:

```
 api("redis.clients:jedis:3.0.1") {
            force = true
        }

api("org.coody.framework:coody-elock:alpha-1.2.4") {
            exclude group: 'redis.clients', module: "jredis"
        }
```

But it does not work,when I compile using this command:

```
gradle build -x test
```

the output jar still using 2.9.1 version,what should I do to fix this?

ENV: Java 8 + Spring Boot 2.1.3 RELEASE + Gradle 6.0

another way tried:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'redis.clients:jedis:3.0.1'
    //循环一个个的依赖库
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {details ->
        //获取当前循环到的依赖库
        def requested = details.requested
        //如果这个依赖库群组的名字是com.android.support
        if (requested.group == 'redis.clients') {
            //且其名字不是以multidex开头的
            //if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                //这里指定需要统一的依赖版本
                details.useVersion '3.0.1'
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

another way:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'redis.clients:jedis:3.0.1'
    }
}
```

still not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find other module using the 2.9.1 version of jar.But I am update my common jar(every module dependency),the proper way is every project should update.By the way I am using api keyword to expose the jedis jar.Finally I solve the problem by write dependencies in other module.It is a bad way but if you did not have any better solution,you can have try.